# How to cronstruct complex data structure in python with zipping multiple data set

Tags: python, json

I have 3 data sets from a json response and would have to merge and restructure them from my end. The 3 data sets are identical in keys and length.

***dev.json***

```
   [  
       {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"passed"
          }
       },
        {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"passed"
          }
       }
    ]
```

***qa.json***

```
   [  
       {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"passed"
          }
       },
        {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"passed"
          }
       }
    ]
```

***prod.json***

```
   [  
       {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"failed"
          }
       },
        {  
          "result":{  
             "duration":0.0,
             "status":"failed"
          }
       }
    ]
```

**I would like to restructure them into this format:**

```
[  
   {  
      "result":{  
         "qa":"passed",
         "dev":"passed",
         "prod":"failed"
      }
   },
   {  
      "result":{  
         "qa":"passed",
         "dev":"passed",
         "prod":"failed"
      }
   }
]
```

**What i've done so far:**

```
with open('qa.json') as data_file:    
    qa = json.load(data_file)

with open('dev.json') as data_file:    
    dev = json.load(data_file)

with open('prod.json') as data_file:    
    prod= json.load(data_file)

#I'm not good with python but this is what i've gotten so far and obviously incorrect
json_list = [dict(list(x[0].items()) + list(x[1].items() + list(x[3].items())) for x in zip(qa,dev,prod)]
```

Coming from a javascript background, I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the list objects and assign a new key

Comment: `json_list = [{'result': {'qa': q['result']['status'], 'dev': d['result']['status'], 'prod': p['result']['status']}} for q, d, p in zip(qa, dev, prod)]`